# WPF Crop image inside a border

Tags: wpf, image, radius

How can i hide the part of the picture that is out of border?

[image]

Here is my xaml code

```
   <Border ClipToBounds="True" CornerRadius="80" Width="350" Background="Black">
        <Image RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Source="imgg.png" Stretch="None" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="60"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Border>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "hide"?

Comment: All you're doing with the border is rounding corners on the picture?you could instead use a rectangle. Make the fill an imagebrush.

Answer (score 0):

To crop an image inside a border in WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation), you can make use of the Clip property of the Image control. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

xaml

```
<Grid>
<Border x:Name="ImageBorder" Width="200" Height="200">
    <Image Source="your_image_source.jpg" Stretch="Uniform">
        <Image.Clip>
            <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,200,200" /> <!-- Specify the cropping dimensions here -->
        </Image.Clip>
    </Image>
</Border>
</Grid>
```

In the above XAML code snippet, we have a Grid container with a Border element inside. The Border represents the visible area or frame within which you want to crop the image. The Image control is placed inside the Border, and the Clip property is set to a RectangleGeometry that defines the cropping dimensions.

Make sure to replace "your_image_source.jpg" with the actual path or URI of your image file.

Adjust the Width and Height properties of the Border element to determine the size of the cropped image.

By modifying the Rect property of the RectangleGeometry, you can specify the dimensions and position of the cropping area. The values are given as follows: (left, top, width, height). In the example, the cropping area is set to start from the top-left corner (0,0) with a width and height of 200 units.

Feel free to modify the dimensions and positioning according to your specific requirements.